# Why is Matan Torah written multiple times in the Torah (with different details..)

Tags: tanach

It seems like the Torah records the story of Moshe going up to get the Torah in parshas yisro and in parshas mishpotim, I noticed different people mentioned regarding who went up with Moshe, also in yisro, bnei yisrael said naaseh and in mishpotim they said naaseh v’nishma. Why is it written twice and how do we understand the differences?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you've had a chance to check out the site [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what it's all about. With that in mind, I hope you don't mind the following recommendation to improve your question and get good answers: consider boiling this down to a single answerable question. If you have more than one question, then please ask them separately - there's no limit! "Why is the Matan Torah mentioned multiple times, and why with the following different details:..." could work. Either way, look forward to learning with you in future.

Comment: It's repeated as well in the Deuteronomy

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Yes, I would love any answers I can get